# Photos Library info reports size in "PB"

Tags: photos

I was touring the Photos app toolbar recently and noticed the little "info" button (same as menu Window/Info, ⌘ I). I pressed it and a dialog appeared showing me info for my entire Photo Library – since I didn't have any photos selected. In the last line of the dialog (full picture below), it says
`129.3 PB`. That appears to be the size of the library, given the clue that the text `calculating size…` appears briefly on that line before the number appears.

What does "PB" stand for? My only guess is petabytes, but that seems large on a 500GB SSD, and with a Finder-reported Photos Library size of 47GB. I've been searching for several days and have only found one [slightly related post](https://www.simplehelp.net/2015/06/01/how-to-fix-a-mac-with-pb-disk-space/). Finder was reporting PB of free space due files in `/.MobileBackups`. I don't have that folder.

I also saw several posts where folks thought Time Machine could cause Finder to be confused about free space. And I do have a Time Machine backup that is taking days to finish. Currently at 12GB of 20GB, which is plausible since I added a ton of files recently.

Is a 129.3 PB Photos Library a sign of something bad? Or just ignore it?

[image: Photos Library Window/Info dialog]

Comment: Do you use iCloud Photo Library?

Comment: Wait for the backup to finish. Then shut down the Mac, disconnect all drives, boot back into it and check again. Have you activated that finder shows hidden files? Otherwise you won't be able to see the `mobileBackups` folder. And just to be clear: 129 Petabytes is not at all possible and macOS/Photos/Finder must misread/misinterpret something to explain this

Comment: I think I don't use iCloud Photo Library, but I'm not certain. I'm only using 2G of the free 5G storage, much smaller than my photos. Although, following the instructions at the link below, I do have Photos selected in the "Apps on this Mac using iCloud". But in Photos/Preferences/iCloud, "iCloud Photos" is turned off. My Photo Stream and Shared Albums are turned on. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264

Comment: To look for for `/.MobileBackups`, I used the terminal command `sudo ls -alh /`. I will let the backup finish and try the clean restart. Though it may just be time to nuke and pave. I used to erase the hard drive for each new macOS, but I've been lazy since I got this MacBook Pro 3 years ago.

Comment: While waiting for the Time Machine backup, I tried the "Repair Library" function of the Photos app. (open app holding option-⌘). I'm still using 129 PB.